# Gitlab CICD Fails to Execute Python Despite Requirements Installed

Tags: python, gitlab, cicd

I have a CICD pipeline to execute some infrastructure deployment stuff with Pulumi, setup in the following .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
prod_job:
  stage: prod
  only:
    - main
  before_script:
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y python3-venv
    - apt-get install -y python3-pip
  script:
    - git submodule init
    - git submodule update
    - python3 -m venv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    - python3 infra.py
```

The results of a pip3 list if run after pip3 install in the CICD pipeline are:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
Arpeggio   2.0.0
attrs      23.1.0
dill       0.3.6
grpcio     1.51.3
parver     0.4
pip        23.0.1
protobuf   4.23.3
pulumi     3.73.0
pulumi-ec  0.5.1
PyYAML     6.0
semver     2.13.0
setuptools 66.1.1
six        1.16.0
```

However, when the infra.py file executes, it fails noting that there is no such file or directory called Pulumi:

> File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pulumi'

The relevant sections of the 'infra.py' file are:

```
import sys
import json
import pulumi
import pulumi_ec as ec

from pulumi import automation as auto
```

Why is this failing to execute if I have properly sourced the virutal environment, and installed the requirements?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [install pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/clouds/aws/get-started/begin/) (which is separate from just installing the Python SDK for Pulumi) in your GitLab job. That is to say, you should be able to call the `pulumi` binary (such as `pulumi version` to show the version of pulumi installed).

The Python code is trying to call this binary and it is failing because it is either not installed or not on PATH.

Comment: It was not in my path... so this was the correct answer. Thank you, I overlooked that and spent too long looking at it for other issues to figure this out.